# Get name of function that passed parameters to current function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the name of a function which called the current function in jquery.

For example, say there are three functions

function a, function b, function c

and when one of those functions call function z, i would like to be able to get a string output of the function that called function z if that is possible please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript provides a mechanism for accessing the current function's callee:

```
function FunctionA() {
    alert(arguments.callee.caller.name);
}

function FunctionB() {
    FunctionA();
}

FunctionB();
```

The following JSFiddle demonstrates this, too.
http://jsfiddle.net/8UFe2/

Answer (score 1):

you would use [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) to get the calling function